# How to loop thorough object and create child component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.js and getting stuck loop thorough child component. I have an object and I need to loop through it which should create child component using the values of that object. Thank you in advance

```
var o = {
    playerA: {
        name: 'a',
    },

    playerB: {
        name: 'b',
    }
};


var Players = React.createClass({
    getPlayers: function(){
        return o;
    },    

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row"> Players</div>
                {this.getPlayers()}
                <Player /> 
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Player = React.createClass({    
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="row" > player {this.name} < /div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Players />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

---

The result should be:

player a

player b

---

I have fiddle set up at:
http://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/7f39Ljbj/

Comment: Have a look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html, "Hook up the data model"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you'll iterate over the data with `.map` so that you can return markup (the child component) for each item. In the child component markup, you pass the data for that item in an attribute.

```
{Object.keys(yourObject).map(function(key) {
  return (
    // Add a key to the list item, it is mandatory from react
    // What the key consists of if it's the id or not is up to you
    // it needs to be unique though
    <ChildComponent key={key} data={yourObject[key]}/>
  );
})}
```

The child component's markup can then use that data by binding `this.props.data`.

```
<div>Player: {this.props.data.name}</div>
```

You don't have to use the name "data" for the attribute/property. Something like `info={yourObject[key]}` with `this.prop.info` is just as valid.

[**Working JS Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2ab18zut/1/)